# Delphi command to write into MSSQL database

Tags: sql-server, delphi

Hi I am trying to write values into a MSSQL express database with Delphi XE7.
I come from an oracle background and am using this command:

```
PRISMProject.frmMain.ADODataSet2.CommandText :=
   'INSERT INTO matter VALUES (Desc,IntRef,InvRef,Cost,MType,AccMan);';
```

matter is the table name.
Can you tell me the syntax for inserting values into a MSSQL database?
Thanks

whole procedure:

```
procedure TfrmMatter.btnSaveClick(Sender: TObject);
var Desc, MType, AccMan : string;
    IntRef, InvRef : integer;
    Cost : double;
begin
  Desc := edtDesc.Text;
  edtDesc.Clear;
  MType := edtType.Text;
  edtType.Clear;
  AccMan := edtAcc.Text;
  edtAcc.Clear;
  if edtIntRef.Text <> '' then
    IntRef := StrToInt(edtIntRef.Text)
  else
    IntRef := 0;
  edtIntRef.Clear;
  if edtInvRef.Text <> '' then
    InvRef := StrToInt(edtInvRef.Text)
  else
    InvRef := 0;
  edtInvRef.Clear;
  if edtCost.Text <> '' then
    Cost := StrToFloat(edtCost.Text)
  else
    Cost := 0;
  edtCost.Clear;
  PRISMProject.frmMain.ADODataSet2.Close;
  PRISMProject.frmMain.ADODataSet2.CommandText :=
  'GO INSERT INTO PRISM.matter VALUES (Desc,IntRef,InvRef,Cost,MType,AccMan)';
  PRISMProject.frmMain.ClientDataSet2.Open;
  PRISMProject.frmMain.ClientDataSet2.Refresh;
  lblConfirm.Caption := 'Matter saved successfully';
  edtDesc.SetFocus;
end;
```

Comment: sorry I mean the name of the table is matter, not the database, the database is connected already and is working in that regard

Comment: ok I read the docs, and now I have PRISMProject.frmMain.ADODataSet2.CommandText :=
   'GO INSERT INTO PRISM.matter VALUES (Desc,IntRef,InvRef,Cost,MType,AccMan);'; which is giving me an error incorrect syntax near ';' any ideas?

Comment: Where do Desc,IntRef,InvRef,Cost,MType,AccMan get their values?  These would normally be constants or parameter names.

Comment: they are variables that save the typed in data from the form, I will add the whole procedure to the question.

Comment: Delphi variables cannot be inserted directly into SQL statements.  You either have to convert them to their values or use parameters to construct your SQL statement.  See Ken's answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to embed variables inside your SQL statement, and that will never work. Once they're between the quotes, they're no longer variables; they're simply text embedded in the SQL statement.

You need to use parameters, and assign your values to those parameters:

```
ADODataSet2.CommandText :=
  'INSERT INTO matter VALUES (:Desc, :IntRef, :InvRef, :Cost, :MType,:AccMan);';

ADODataSet2.Parameters.ParamByName('Desc').Value := Desc;
ADODataSet2.Parameters.ParamByName('IntRef').Value := IntRef;
ADODataSet2.Parameters.ParamByName('Cost').Value := Cost;
// etc. for the rest of the parameters and values
```

With all that being said, you're doing things the hard way. `TADODataSet` supports `Insert` and `Append` directly, so you don't even need the SQL statement at all.

```
ADODataSet2.Insert;
ADODataSet2.FieldByName('Desc').Value := Desc;
ADODataSet2.FieldByName('IntRef').Value := IntRef;
ADODataSet2.FieldByName('Cost').Value := Cost;
// etc for remaining fields
ADODataSet2.Post;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's the MSDN documentation on how to do an insert:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx

Here's another article with some example of inserts, if the above documentation is a bit too technical. One of these should cover what you're trying to do.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776381(v=sql.105).aspx

The other thing I'll mention is that you have to reference a table in the database, not just the database. So your insert is close to on the right track, but it'd be closer to

```
insert into matter.<schema>.<tableName> (desc, intref, invref, cost, mtype, accman)
...
```